# Python : Separating a .txt file into columns and finding the most frequent data item in one of the columns

Tags: python, data-structures, syntax, pandas

I read from a file and stored into artists_tag with column names .
Now this file has multiple columns and I need to generate a new data structure which has 2 columns from the artists_tag as it is and the most frequent value from the 'Tag' column as the 3rd column value.
Here is what I have written as of now:

```
import pandas as pd
    from collections import Counter

def parse_artists_tags(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="|", names=["ArtistID", "ArtistName", "Tag", "Count"])
    return df

def parse_user_artists_matrix(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    return df

# artists_tags = parse_artists_tags(DATA_PATH + "\\artists-tags.txt")
artists_tags = parse_artists_tags("C:\\Users\\15-J001TX\\Documents\\ml_task\\artists-tags.txt")

#print(artists_tags)
user_art_mat = parse_user_artists_matrix("C:\\Users\\15-J001TX\\Documents\\ml_task\\userart-mat-training.csv")

#print ("Number of tags {0}".format(len(artists_tags))) # Change this line. Should be 952803
#print ("Number of artists {0}".format(len(user_art_mat))) # Change this line. Should be 17119

# TODO Implement this. You can change the function arguments if necessary
# Return a data structure that contains (artist id, artist name, top tag) for every artist
def calculate_top_tag(all_tags):
    temp = all_tags.Tag
    a = Counter(temp)
    a = a.most_common()
    print (a)
    top_tags = all_tags.ArtistID,all_tags.ArtistName,a;
    return top_tags

top_tags = calculate_top_tag(artists_tags)

# Print the top tag for Nirvana
# Artist ID for Nirvana is 5b11f4ce-a62d-471e-81fc-a69a8278c7da
# Should be 'Grunge'
print ("Top tag for Nirvana is {0}".format(top_tags)) # Complete this line
```

In the last method calculate_top_tag I don't understand how to choose the most frequent value from the 'Tag' column and put it as the third column for top_tags before returning it.

I am new to python and my knowledge of syntax and data structures is limited. I did try the various solutions mentioned for finding the most frequent value from the list but they seem to display the entire column and not one particular value. I know this is some trivial syntax issue but after having searched for long I still cannot figure out how to get this one.

edit 1 :
I need to find the most common tag for a particular artist and not the most common overall.
But again, I don't know how to.

edit 2 :
here is the link to the data files:
https://github.com/amplab/datascience-sp14/raw/master/hw2/hw2data.tar.gz

Comment: Can you please describe in detail the structure of each of your files?  I.e. in the `artist_tags` file, what exactly is the list of columns, and what is meant by a single row.  Similarly, in the `artist_matrix` file, what exactly is the list of columns and what is meant by a single row.  (Please indicate the files as they are when you read them from disk, *not* what you want them to contain once you're done working on them.)  Then, separately, what *exactly* do you want to compute. It would help if you could show a few rows of each input file and what output you want.

Comment: Not super encouraging to actually see the source data labelled as homework...

Comment: shouldn't make much difference if the Q is legit enough right?
Besides I am not enrolled into the course...I am a self learner practicing ML via various exercises...Can you please point out how to solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a more succint way of doing it, but this should get you started:

```
# returns a df grouped by ArtistID and Tag
tag_counts = artists_tags.groupby(['ArtistID', 'Tag'])
# sum up tag counts and sort in descending order
tag_counts = tag_counts.sum().sort('Count', ascending=False).reset_index()
# keep only the top ranking tag per artist
top_tags = tag_counts.groupby('ArtistID').first()
# top_tags is now a dataframe which contains the top tag for every artist
# We can simply lookup the top tag for Nirvana via it's index:
top_tags.ix['5b11f4ce-a62d-471e-81fc-a69a8278c7da'][0]
# 'Grunge'
```